# help with LibSVM input data

Tags: windows, input, libsvm

I am using the LibSVM tool for my support vector classification implementation:-

The first line in my input data file looks as so:-

```
+1 15752:47 6279:45 475:40 5231:30 515:29 7529:28 11623:24 274:24 15431:21 7342:20 4819:20 7598:18 8853:17 11134:16 501:16 911:15 4656:15 5875:14 10725:13 7334:13 13762:13 8295:12 9314:12 317:12 10641:12 2690:12 8771:12 4698:11 11519:10 10069:9 10019:8 1120:8 15017:8 254:8 7900:8 5395:8 486:8 1763:8 11183:7 9163:7 9219:7 1827:7 11901:7 4068:6 15592:6 9925:6 3464:5 8408:5 15348:5 8432:5 10064:5 6319:4 5729:4 8334:4 11817:4 6238:4 4521:4 11761:4 328:4 15876:4 6494:4 280:4 14628:4 5514:4 6383:4 9149:4 2456:4 6741:4 482:4 2773:4 10873:3 8715:3 8802:3 11478:3 11848:3 12269:3 10592:3 12911:3 11051:3 10798:3 8412:3 232:3 7654:3 1210:3 502:3 12687:3 14459:2 2725:2 9851:2 5799:2 16046:2 3612:2 1440:2 8503:2 245:2 9780:2 322:2 11902:2 8977:2 14949:2 5710:2 6423:2 9896:2 5507:2 10646:2 9932:2 14894:2 3997:2 13429:2 9845:2 8547:2 2720:2 861:2 2830:2 5703:2 6994:2 13973:2 3086:2 262:2 7793:2 208:2 3221:2 13229:2 13350:2 372:2 10384:2 3970:2 13506:2 9720:2 8981:2 9296:1 10276:1 15098:1 6631:1 383:1 6510:1 13304:1 9646:1 8233:1 1080:1 8537:1 12129:1 10711:1 14569:1 2969:1 1215:1 12435:1 7689:1 12626:1 14609:1 13474:1 4488:1 103:1 621:1 12430:1 617:1 514:1 11673:1 215:1 8817:1 10968:1 4717:1 1807:1 5737:1 3156:1 14320:1 13457:1 12411:1 9596:1 15028:1 10531:1 4301:1 4799:1 6013:1 7619:1 6717:1 9344:1 1817:1 15868:1 11307:1 9632:1 6945:1 9916:1 11899:1 883:1 11696:1 14503:1 316:1 4012:1 9994:1 8501:1 1847:1 12534:1 14966:1 11800:1 8093:1 13403:1 7309:1 5957:1 6538:1 2535:1 7042:1 13792:1 15001:1 4894:1 4921:1 13739:1 15875:1 15802:1 14253:1 10376:1 974:1 1882:1 2397:1 8105:1 4725:1 7707:1 7506:1 9749:1 8640:1 12566:1
```

The name of my input data file is --> a1a

I tried to run the program on my windows command prompt as

```
svm-train a1a
```

I get the following error

```
Wrong input format at line 1
```

Could somebody help me out here? I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature numbers (14253, 10376, etc) have to be listed in increasing order. Once you do that, svm-train will take that data. So, for example, your file needs to begin:

```
+1 103:1 208:2 215:1 232:3 245:2 254:8 262:2 274:24 280:4 316:1 317:12 322:2 328:4 372:2 383:1 475:40 482:4 486:8 501:16 502:3 514:1 515:29 617:1 621:1 861:2 883:1 911:15 974:1 1080:1 1120:8 1210:3 1215:1 1440:2 1763:8 1807:1 1817:1 1827:7 1847:1 1882:1 2397:1 2456:4 2535:1 2690:12 2720:2 2725:2 2773:4 2830:2 2969:1 3086:2 3156:1 3221:2 3464:5 3612:2 3970:2 3997:2 4012:1 4068:6 4301:1 4488:1 4521:4 4656:15 4698:11 4717:1 4725:1 4799:1 4819:20 4894:1 4921:1 5231:30 5395:8 5507:2 5514:4 5703:2 5710:2 5729:4 5737:1 5799:2 5875:14 5957:1 6013:1 6238:4 6279:45 6319:4 6383:4 6423:2 6494:4 6510:1 6538:1 6631:1 6717:1 6741:4 6945:1 6994:2 7042:1 7309:1 7334:13 7342:20 7506:1 7529:28 7598:18 7619:1 7654:3 7689:1 7707:1 7793:2 7900:8 8093:1 8105:1 8233:1 8295:12 8334:4 8408:5 8412:3 8432:5 8501:1 8503:2 8537:1 8547:2 8640:1 8715:3 8771:12 8802:3 8817:1 8853:17 8977:2 8981:2 9149:4 9163:7 9219:7 9296:1 9314:12 9344:1 9596:1 9632:1 9646:1 9720:2 9749:1 9780:2 9845:2 9851:2 9896:2 9916:1 9925:6 9932:2 9994:1 10019:8 10064:5 10069:9 10276:1 10376:1 10384:2 10531:1 10592:3 10641:12 10646:2 10711:1 10725:13 10798:3 10873:3 10968:1 11051:3 11134:16 11183:7 11307:1 11478:3 11519:10 11623:24 11673:1 11696:1 11761:4 11800:1 11817:4 11848:3 11899:1 11901:7 11902:2 12129:1 12269:3 12411:1 12430:1 12435:1 12534:1 12566:1 12626:1 12687:3 12911:3 13229:2 13304:1 13350:2 13403:1 13429:2 13457:1 13474:1 13506:2 13739:1 13762:13 13792:1 13973:2 14253:1 14320:1 14459:2 14503:1 14569:1 14609:1 14628:4 14894:2 14949:2 14966:1 15001:1 15017:8 15028:1 15098:1 15348:5 15431:21 15592:6 15752:47 15802:1 15868:1 15875:1 15876:4 16046:2
```